# error- forbids comparison between pointer and integer and how to use user input to other function?

Tags: c

In the seat reservation that I am working on, I used `if(p.name == passengername)`to get user input to update its input. But it says error.

````
forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
         if(p.name == passengername)```
````

I declared `passengername` as `char` but it is not working. Am I doing it wrong? I assumed that `p.name` is a char so that I can compare it to the `char passengername` that I declared.

And what do I need to do to get user's input in `chooseseat()` so that I can use it in `reserve();` When I print it the `p.seatcol` and `p.seatrow` in `fprintf` displays `0`. What do I need to do to save users input in  `chooseseat();` to `reserve();`?

Below is the part of my sample program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>


#define ROWS 11
#define COLS 8
#define PASSENGERSIZE sizeof(passenger)

typedef struct{
    char city[20], name[50], seatcol;
    int age, seatrow, id;
    unsigned int seatnum;

}passenger;

void chooseseat();

void reserve(){
    passenger p;
    FILE *fp, *fp1;

    fp=fopen("passenger.txt", "a+");
    fp1=fopen("passenger1.txt", "a+");
    
    printf("\n\t\t\tEnter your name:");
    scanf(" %s",p.name);

    chooseseat();
    write(&p, PASSENGERSIZE, 1, fp1);
    fprintf(fp, " %s\t%d%c",p.name, p.seatrow,p.seatcol);
    
fclose(fp);
fclose(fp1);
}

void chooseseat(){
    passenger p;
    // Read the user input until it reserves a seat or request quitting.
    
        // Read user input.
        printf("\nEnter your seat number: (EX: 1A)");
        scanf(" %d%c",&p.seatrow, &p.seatcol);

        // Check if the seat requested is valid entry.
        if (p.seatrow > 0 && p.seatrow < ROWS &&
            p.seatcol >= 'A' && p.seatcol <= 'A' + COLS){

                // Input range is valid, check if seat is already taken.
                if (seat[p.seatrow - 1][p.seatcol - 'A'] != 'X'){
                    // Seat is available, reserve it and break the loop.
                    seat[p.seatrow - 1][p.seatcol - 'A'] = 'X';
                    printf("Congratulations. Your seat number is %d%c\n",p.seatrow,p.seatcol);
                }
                else{
                    // Seat is already taken.
                    printf("Seat is already taken. Choose another seat? (Y/N)\n.");
                    scanf(" %c", &answer);
                if (answer != 'Y'){
                    printf("Your data will be not saved and will be returned to main menu.\n");
                }
        }
        
    }
    else{
            // Input range is invalid.
            printf("Invalid seat row/col,\n");
}
}
void display(){

    passenger p;

    FILE *fp, *fp1;

    fp=fopen("passenger.txt", "r");
    fp1=fopen("passenger1.txt", "r");

    while(fread(&p, PASSENGERSIZE, 1, fp1)){
        printf(" \n%s\t%d%c",p.name,p.seatrow,p.seatcol);
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
}

void update(){

    FILE *fp, *fp1, *fp2;

    char passengername;
    int found=0;

    fp=fopen("passenger.txt", "r");
    fp1=fopen("passenger1.txt", "r");
    fp2=fopen("temp.txt","w");

    printf("\n\t\t\tEnter roll number to update: ");
    scanf(" %c", &passengername);

    while(fread(&p, PASSENGERSIZE, 1, fp1)){
        if(p.name == passengername){

            found=1;
            displayseat();

            printf("\n\t\t\tUpdate your seat number: (EX: 1A)");
            scanf(" %d%c",&p.seatrow, &p.seatcol);
        }fwrite(&p, PASSENGERSIZE, 1, fp2);
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

}
int main(){

    int selection;

    do{printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t************WELCOME TO C AIRLINES********");

    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t CHOOSE A MENU OPTION: ");
    printf("\n");

        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t [1] ENTER A RESERVATION");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t [2] EDIT A RESERVATION");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t [3] DISPLAY RESERVATION");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t [0] EXIT");

        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t=============================\n");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\tPlease Enter Any : ");
        scanf("%d",&selection);

        switch(selection){
        case 1: reserve();
        break;
        case 2: update();
        break;
        case 3: display();
        break;
        default:
        break;
        }
}while(selection!=0);
}
```

Comment: Seeing your recent history of questions, some of which were quite similar, allow me to recommend to you to generally change your programming approach. Please split your projects into smaller steps. Try one thing, find help with that, implement and improve. Then test that, separately. Until you are satisfied. Then, to add something, start a new toy project to first get to grips with that new aspect. Implemet, improve, test that. Then spend explicit effort on intgegrating the second into the existing project. Then repeat. You are asking to separate questions here, which is quite the opposite.

Comment: This is very similar advice to https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Answer (score 2):

Your `passengername` is a single `char`.
For one, the compiler considers that a single integer (of small width), this is what causes your error.
For another, you need more than one `char` there, since you want to store a name. Use a char array like you did for `p.name`.
Then what you want to do is compare strings via pointers to them, not pointers.
So switch from `==` (comparing pointers) to `strcmp()`. ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp )
Or even better, `strncmp()`.

Comment: I see, I noticed my errors. I changed it as `passengername[50]` and `%s`. and I tried `strcmp()` and declared it as `char result;` and define it as `result= strcmp(p.seatrow, p.seatcol)` but it runs an error saying invalid conversion because my p.seatrow is an int and p.seatcol is a char. or am I using it incorrectly

Comment: You are trying to use the string-comparison function for comparing integer data? And for comparing single character data? Sorry, I think I must have misunderstood you. Please read my comment on the question. Do smaller things. If you have to work on strings and integers, first work on integers until that works. Then look into the more complex issue of doing similar with strings. Spend some time with some tutorials on single `char` and arrays of `char` and the very similar but not identical concept of 0-terminated character sequences; which is the closest C gets to having strings.

Comment: If you have problems with comparing integers please ask a new separate question on that, with dedicated [mre].

Comment: I see, Thank you very much. This is the first project that has been given to me and still unfamiliar with the basics of c. I apologize to ask different questions similarly, but this is very helpful.  I'll take note of all of your pointers and will work on them. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

There's a bunch of issues here.

I'll concentrate just on the `update()` function, because this is the place of your current issue.

Firstly, the code around the reported compilation error is using a variable named `p`.  This variable has not been declared in the scope of function `update()`.  Looking at the rest of your code, reading [a few tutorials](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=c%20programming%20variable%20scope%20tutorial&ia=web) on C variable scope would be good.

The code is comparing `p.name` (char[50]) with `passengername` (char).  The reason you're seeing this error is the char-array `p.name` ultimately is treated as a pointer, whereas `passengername` is a single character (perhaps you meant this to be a char-array too?).  The single character is basically a small integer (1 byte).

This means that the statement:

```
if ( p.name == passengername )
```

resolves to:

```
if ( pointer-to-array-of-char == char )
```

which degrades to:

```
if ( pointer == number )
```

I can only guess at what the intention of the code is, but perhaps something like this is more what you desired:

```
void update()
{
    FILE *fp, *fp1, *fp2;
    passenger p;                                      // <<-- HERE define  'p'
    char passengername[sizeof(passenger.name)];       // <<-- HERE array, not char
    int found=0;

    fp  = fopen("passenger.txt", "r");
    fp1 = fopen("passenger1.txt", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("temp.txt","w");

    printf("\n\t\t\tEnter roll number to update: ");
    fgets( passengername, sizeof(passenger.name), stdin );        // <<-- HERE fgets()
    // TODO, Handle \n from fgets()

    while( fread( &p, sizeof(passenger), 1, fp1 ) ) 
    {
        if ( strcmp( p.name, passengername ) == 0 )      // <<-- HERE strcmp()
        {
            found=1;
            displayseat();

            printf( "\n\t\t\tUpdate your seat number: (EX: 1A)" );
            scanf( " %d%c", &p.seatrow, &p.seatcol );
        }

        fwrite( &p, sizeof(passenger), 1, fp2 );
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

}
```

- Errors and omissions expected.  I made no attempt to fix *all* the errors in the code.